# Return the value of a cell in range by addressing the range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two columns with Excel Names Days and Ref I have some VBA that goes down Days and if the number of days is less than 730 it highlights the cell green, I also want the ref from the Ref column for that row, it's in column A. I don't want to use OFFSET to get the value as the columns may change is there a way to get the Ref value using the Ref named range? Or other means.

The code I am using is

```
Sub Days()

    Dim myDaysRange As Range
    Dim myDays As Range

    Set myDaysRange = Selection
    
    For Each myDays In myDaysRange
    
        If myDays.Value < 730 Then
            
            myDays.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            'Here I also want the Ref value from Col A of the same row without referring to Col A but the named range "Ref" in case the column order changes.


        End If
        
    Next myDays
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not well-written. Please add (much) more detail about your spreadsheet, VBA, and what you are trying to do.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497990/how-to-reference-named-column-in-excel-vba

Comment: After you set `myDaysRange`, use the `Range.Find` method to locate the `Ref` header, then calculate the offset between the two columns, using that in your loop.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's interesting, but could I get the row the cell and then use that with INDEX to get the Ref?

Comment: I suggest using `myDays.Offset`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld O specifically don't want to use this in case columns are moved around.

Comment: Perhaps you are not understanding something?  I don't see how that can possibly be an issue unless you are moving the columns while the macro is executing (and you don't show that in your code).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld What I mean is say Ref is column A, and Days is column C and I use OFFSET to refer to col A, that's fine. But what if Days is moved to column E when the macro then runs using OFFSET it will refer to col C which would be wrong. I'm still building the spreadsheet and don't want to worry about moving columns messing up the macro.

Comment: I know you read my first comment above because you responded to it. What did you think I meant when I wrote : ***then calculate the offset between the two columns, using that in your loop.***  If you know where your Days column is (presumeable `Selection` although it is bad practice to use `Select`) and you know where `Ref` is (from the Find), the offset will be the difference in columns between the two.  Since you calculate that ***each time you run the macro***, what does it matter if you've moved `Ref`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld OIC

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight

- Test the accuracy of the code by moving the used range (table) all around the worksheet after adjusting the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightDaysAndRef()

    ' Both
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cColor As Long = vbGreen
    ' Source
    Const sHeader As String = "Days"
    Const sCriteria As Double = 730
    ' Destination
    Const dHeader As String = "Ref"
    
    ' Workbook, Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Used Range ('urg').
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim urCount As Long: urCount = urg.Rows.Count
    If urCount = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = urg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Header Cell ('shCell').
    Dim shCell As Range
    Set shCell = urg.Find(sHeader, urg.Cells(urCount, cCount), _
        xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    If shCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the '" & sHeader & "' header.", _
            vbCritical, "Header Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range ('scrg').
    Dim hRow As Long: hRow = shCell.Row
    Dim ufRow As Long: ufRow = urg.Row
    Dim rOff As Long: rOff = hRow - ufRow
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = urg.Resize(urCount - rOff).Offset(rOff)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = Intersect(trg, shCell.EntireColumn)
    
    ' Write the Destination Header Column to a variable ('dcol').
    Dim hrrg As Range: Set hrrg = trg.Rows(1)
    Dim dhCell As Range
    Set dhCell = hrrg.Find(dHeader, hrrg.Cells(cCount), _
        xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If dhCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the '" & dHeader & "' header.", _
            vbCritical, "Header Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim dCol As Long: dCol = dhCell.Column
    
    ' Combine cells to highlight into the Highlight Range ('hlrg').
    Dim hlrg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    For Each sCell In scrg.Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            If sValue < sCriteria Then
                Set hlrg = GetCombinedRange(hlrg, Union( _
                    sCell, sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)))
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    ' Remove hightlights.
    Union(scrg, scrg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)).Interior.Color = xlNone
    
    ' Highlight the desired cells.
    If hlrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to highlight.", vbExclamation, "Highlight"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    hlrg.Interior.Color = cColor
    
    ' Inform of success.
    MsgBox "Cells highlighted.", vbInformation, "Highlight"
    
End Sub

Function GetCombinedRange( _
    ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set GetCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set GetCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```